# ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index 40 - Python & CURL

Tags: python, curl

I'm trying to create a program that can analyze the speed of a website in the terminal. I have used the curl module to process the command in Linux shell. But I'm getting the following error.

`ValueError: unsupported format character '{' (0x7b) at index 40`

```
import subprocess

def webSpeed():
    website = raw_input("Enter name of the website:  ")
    print(website)
    cmd = "curl -s -w 'Website Response Time for :%{url_effective}\n\nLookup Time:\t\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect Time:\t\t%{time_connect}\nAppCon Time:\t\t%{time_appconnect}\nRedirect Time:\t\t%{time_redirect}\nPre-transfer Time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStart-transfer Time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal Time:\t\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null https://%s" %(webiste)
    print(cmd)
    temp = subprocess.call(cmd, shell="TRUE")
    print(temp)
```

How can I add curl commands in python if it's using curly braces?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do

```
string % format_values
```

Then every `%` in *string* is treated as formatting place. Python found `%{` and was confused - it expected `%d` for placing integers or `%s` for placing strings, or something else know to it. But formatting code does not use `%{` for any format - thus error.  When you want to write `%` which does not have formatting meaning then you should escape it by another `%`.

Therefore there are two solutions

1. either change all % (except last `%s`) with `%%`
2. or do not use `string % format_values` but simply add website to
   your command since luckily it is at the end

Correct and wrong code examples:

```
website = "lukaszslusarczyk.pl"
cmd1 = "curl -s -w 'Response Time for %%{url_effective}\t%%{time_connect}\n' -o /dev/null https://%s" % website # OK                                                                                                                  
cmd2 = "curl -s -w 'Response Time for %{url_effective}\t%{time_connect}\n' -o /dev/null https://" + website # OK                                                                                                                      
cmd3 = "curl -s -w 'Response Time for %{url_effective}\t%{time_connect}\n' -o /dev/null https://%s" % website # wrong
```